Question about embedded integrable submanifolds in Fröbenius theorem.
Let $\omega$ be a nowhere vanishing integrable covector field on a simply connected manifold $M$. Fröbenius theorem then guarantee that for each $p\in M$ there exists a unique maximal integral manifold of $\omega$. This integrable manifold is always an injectively immersed submanifold of $M$. My question is: what are the necessary and sufficient conditions on $\omega$ such that the integrable manifold is an embedding?

If the integral submanifolds are compat, then they are embedded. Not sure if there is an easy characterisation in terms of $\omega$ though. For example consider the torus
$$T = \mathbb R^2 / \mathbb Z^2,$$
with coordinates $x,y$.
The vector field
$$X_1 = \frac \partial {\partial x}$$
has leaves $\{x = c\}$ for $c \in \mathbb R$, which is isomorphic to $S^1$, so compact. But the leaves of
$$X_2 = \frac \partial {\partial x} + \sqrt2 \frac \partial {\partial y}$$
are the images of the lines
$$L_c = \{y = \sqrt 2x + c\} \subset \mathbb R^2.$$
The immersion $L_c \to T$ is injective, so the integral manifold cannot be compact, and is dense in $T$.
